# JSP adds HTML to the view but doesn't execute it to the user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I wanted to insert html code to a jsp page so I used normal spring controller populated my model with html items, then once I start to render the data on the view ,it show the user a row html tags rather than an actual elements like:

```
<p> <strong> Description:</strong></p>
```

I wanted to show the user an actual strong text not the tag itself ,anyone knows how to achieve that?
my view is like that:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
<c:out value="${Description}" escapeXml="false" />
</body>
</html>
```

any Idea how to solve it?

Edit : part of the code where I send the html :

```
model.addAttribute("Description", jobpost.getDescription()
            .replace("&lt;", "<")
            .replace("&gt;", ">")
            .replace("&amp;", "&")
            .replace("&quot;", "\"")
            .replace("&apos;", "\\"));
```

Edit 2 : it finally worked guys It was a problem with the above code I forgot to insert ; at the end of & lt;

Comment: I have awarded the first person answered the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wrapping the field with `<b>` or `<h2>`tag

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
<b><c:out value="${Description}" escapeXml="false" /></b> // like this
</body><
/html>
```

Comment: I have tried the code above it just prints the same code but bolder instead it's a nice try even though it didn't work

Comment: if I used out.print() it does print the html but I have no idea how to get the model data inside the <% %> tag

Comment: You can use <%= Description %> for this. Please try

Comment: Or could you explain exactly what you are looking to acheive.

Comment: I will try that now

Comment: An error occurred at line: [11] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/index.jsp]
Description cannot be resolved to a variable
8: <h1>My First Heading</h1>
9: <p>This is our message: </p>
10: 
11: <%= Description %>
12: </body>
13: </html>
14: Have I wrote it in the correct way?

Comment: Are you sending a variable named Description to the jsp form. As it is not able to find a variable name Description or you can use try `<%= request.getAttribute("Description") %>

Or if it is just a text you want to print you can use `<%= "Description" %>`

Comment: Thanks a lot have been solved due to error in html escaping characters